# Bug: Can't insert horizontal rule in Safari on iOS

Tags: bug, markdown

Normally we can create a horizontal line in questions or answers like this:

```
-------
```

However, in Safari for iOS, I found no way to enter this sequence of characters, since two sequential dashes are converted to an "em dash" automatically.

Comment: It's not really our bug. It's a setting in iOS or on your device. You need to turn it off. Related question on Super User: https://superuser.com/q/555628/496411 this isn't about mobile Safari, though, so I'm not certain where the setting lives.

Answer (score 4):

Well, they don't on my iPhone. Proof:

---

You can disable this automatic conversion via the Settings app → General → Keyboards and make sure the setting "Smart Punctuation" is switched off. It *is* smart, but not meant for programmers.

Alternatively, use HTML; `<hr/>` works as well:

---